# Resolving "HaikuTextView cannot be resolved or is not a field" error

Tags: android

The HaikuTextView is a reference to TextView and the code is following:

```
package android.love1;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.content.Intent; 
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class HaikuDisplay1 extends Activity { /** Called when the activity is first     created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
 {
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   setContentView(R.layout.main); 
 }

 public void onLoveButtonClicked(View view) {
    TextView textView =(TextView) findViewById(R.id.HaikuTextView);
    textView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

Comment: edit your question, format your code.

Comment: Agreed with @mihail. You need to actually ask a question, provide details, and show the full relevant code--that includes whatever calls `onLoveButtonClicked`, as well as your `main.xml` layout file.

Answer (score 1):

From the error you have described in your title, one of the possibility for getting this error is because you do not have any textview with an id of `HaikuTextView`

Do the following checks:

Check the `R. java` in the `gen` folder of your application. If there exists any

```
public static final class id {
 public static final int HaikuTextView=0x7f0b0213;
```

}

Or check in your main.xml layout file if you have any `TextView` with an id of `HaikuTextView`